# I cant get keyboard.wait to continue with the code after pressing a key

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm making a script in python that shouldn't continue with the script until after I've pressed a certain key (in this case that key is Y) but every time I get to that part of the script and press the key it just ends the program prematurely. I don't quite know if I'm missing something or just being mildly retarded.

```
import random
import time
import keyboard

loop = True
while loop == True:

north = random.randint(0,90)
south = random.randint(0,90)
west = random.randint(0,180)
east = random.randint(0,180)
nors = random.randint(0, 1)
eorw = random.randint(0, 1)

Snorth = str(north)
Ssouth = str(south)
Swest = str(west)
Seast = str(east)

if nors == 1:
    print("north: " , Snorth)
    time.sleep(.5)

else:
    print("south: " , Ssouth)
    time.sleep(.5)

if eorw == 1:
    print("west: " , Swest)
    print("Again?")
    if keyboard.wait('"y"'):
        print("test")
        loop = True
        time.wait(5)

    else:
        loop = False

else:
    print("east: " , Seast)
    print("Again?")
    if keyboard.wait("y"):
        print("test")
        loop = True
        time.wait(5)

    else:
        loop = False
```

Comment: `keyboard.wait()` doesn't return any value so you can't use it as if condition. replace it with another function like input() or mvcrt.getch()

Comment: for example you can use `input()` like this : `if input('Again?') == 'y':` and remember to delete `print("Again?")` to prevent printing `Again?` twice! and replace `time.wait(5)` with `time.sleep(5)` otherwise you'll get errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `keyboard.read_key()` function instead, as `keyboard.wait()` only blocks execution until the key is pressed, and returns a **NoneType** which fails in your if-else statement.

```
while loop:
    north = random.randint(0,90)
    south = random.randint(0,90)
    west = random.randint(0,180)
    east = random.randint(0,180)
    nors = random.randint(0, 1)
    eorw = random.randint(0, 1)

    if nors == 1:
        print("north: " , str(north))
    else:
        print("south: " , str(south))

    if eorw == 1:
        print("west: " , str(west))
    else:
        print("east: " , str(east))

    print("Again?")
    if keyboard.read_key() == "y":
        loop = True
    else:
        loop = False
```

From the documentation
(https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardread_keysuppressfalse): 
 **keyboard.read_key()** blocks until a keyboard event happens, then returns that event's name or, if missing, its scan code.